# Simple Dom Parser Returns Empty via Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, parsing, preg-replace, domparser

I'm using [Simple HTML Dom Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) to correct some links in my output to good effect but have found some strange behaviour when calling content via Ajax. I'm using the parser on a WordPress site so feed the `$content` variable into the following function:

```
function add_trailing_slash( $content ) {

    $content = str_get_html( $content );
    if( $content ):
        foreach( $content->find('a') as $a ):

            if( isset( $a->href ) && '' !== $a->href && '#' !== $a->href ):

                // replace http with https on all link hrefs
                $a->href = str_replace('http:', 'https:', $a->href);

                // checks if link lacks trailing slash and appends it if no extension (file)
                $ext = pathinfo( $a->href, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                if( '/' !== substr( $a->href, -1 ) && ! $ext ) $a->href = $a->href . '/';

            endif;

        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $content;
}
```

This is working great when added to `the_content` filter with `add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_trailing_slash' )` and even when called directly like `return add_trailing_slash( $output )` however, when I call the same function via Ajax I get a 'success' response but which is completely empty. Stranger still, I found that if I return the output via `wpautop( $output )` it comes back just fine. `wpautop` ([link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/)) is essentially a bunch of `preg_replace` functions to replace double line breaks with `<p>` tags so I tested returning my output via `return preg_replace('<blah>', '', $content)` and it worked!

Oh, I also tested removing all my changes from the `add_trailing_slash()` function above and the same issue persisted so I guess that something to do with the way `str_get_html( $content )` parses the input makes it not play well with the Ajax callback. But why does `preg_replace` make it returnable?

```
function add_trailing_slash( $content ) {

    $content = str_get_html( $content );
    return $content;
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this issue, whether I'm missing something and this is expected or whether this is a bug? I could leave in my `preg_replace` which appears to 'fix' the issue but it feels like something of a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that come to my mind is that when you do $content = str_get_html( $content ); you are getting an object as result. Maybe when it goes through wp functions it get interpreted like a string but when you are json_encoding it, something may go wrong and kill it. You can either try to force-cast it to string with

```
return (string) $content;
```

or try to use

```
// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into string
$str = $html->save();
```

as described in the docs

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, @Diego. Both of those proposed solutions absolutely work. I've gone with the second `$html->save()` method but tested both. All makes sense now.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so it result closed and it will help others in the future